# utf-8 using exchange behind postfix workaround?

Tags: postfix, exchange-2013, utf-8

We have a problem with mail bouncing due to UTF-8.

we have a smtpin (postfix) --->KEMP load balancer ----> exchange 2013

We have a company that needs to send mail to some of our users and they are using mailgun.com to send the mails. Thay are using SMTPUTF8 in header and sender address. our postfix can handle SMTPUTF8 but not our exchange, we are getting "SMTPUTF8 is required, but was not offered by host x.x.x.x <-- load balancer IP)

Seems we can´t activate UTF-8 on exchange 2013 so the question is if there is some kind of workaround?

mail are not really my speciality, but can you use aliases and virtual_map or something to transcode the emails to unicode before it reaches the exchange?

thanks in advance.

/Robert

Answer (score 0):

Which character set is your Exchange Server using? You could run the command **Get-RemoteDomain | fl Identity, CharacterSet, NonMimeCharacterSet** to check that:
[image]
Besides, here is one related thread for your reference, hope it's helpful to you: **[Exchange 2013 UTF-8 characters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/355a44d0-48a9-4d7c-85cf-2936357cd1a1/exchange-2013-utf8-characters?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaging)**